# Batch find in folder structure and replace with other file with automator

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, automator

Whoo, tough one.

I have one folder with photos (several subfolders) and another folder (with a different subfolder-structure) containing thumbnail. Now I have to go through each file of folder one, look in the folder-structure of folder 2 if there is a file with the same name and replace it if yes.

With automator, I can filter out all images from folder 1, but how to process them in order to do the rest? Script?

Is there a way to do this completely in a script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a shell script like this:

```
find folder1 -name '*.jpg' | while read f; do
  f2=$(find folder2 -name "${f##*/}")
  [[ $f2 ]] && cp "$f" "$f2"
done
```

`${f##*/}` removes the longest pattern matching `*/` from the start of `$f`. `[[ $f2 ]]` is equivalent to `[[ -n $f2 ]]` and it tests if `$f2` has non-zero length.

Comment: Thanks mate, made my day! In about 3500 images, there were only about 15 or so, where the script failed. I think, its because there were several files with the same name - but thats about 0,5% of the photos, so its no problem.